# Split string values in dataframe to numpy floating values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and it's columns have floating values but in string format.
How can I convert string values into float and the store them in a numpy array?

eg:

```
0   252485  '11.928911999999999 4.9965290000000016 0.0 0.0 ...'     '2.490541199999999 -6.533438 3.7505536 4.933191...' 1 0
```

this is the first row from the dataframe
i want it to look like

```
[[11.928911999999999 4.9965290000000016 0.0 0.0 ... 2.490541199999999 -6.533438 3.7505536 4.933191...]]
```

[image]

Comment: `'11.928911999999999 4.9965290000000016 0.0 0.0 ...'` - is that a string containing multiple numbers?

Comment: yes @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: `np.array(s.split())` where s is your string, you can apply this logic in series.

Comment: @anky_91 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute split()

Comment: please post a testable dataframe fragment (don't post input as image)

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this worked for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([{'0': '5421736', '1': '12.9839834 1.29748374 4.8293'},
                   {'0': '13423',  '1': '19.43434 98.8934783674545 5.3456789'},
                   {'0': '39423',  '1': '9.423283434 0.563763648 123.17637364 34.8973493740'}])

df['new_1'] = df['1'].map(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x.split()])

#test the output:
df.iloc[0]['new_1']
```